# Testing an Android keyboard service

Tags: android, android-service

I have cloned Google's SoftKeyboard example from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/ec1f72d17dbbfd8012e0c4164f62b82ff2e7a9a9/samples/SoftKeyboard?autodive=0%2F).

Obviously I cannot launch a service to test it like a normal application; so my question is how do I launch (not the correct word) the service?